# What causes Error in ogrInfo when using readOGR to open a layer in a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, r, leaflet

When I use readOGR to read a shapefile from thematicmapping.org, the shapefile is successfully displayed by leaflet in a shinyapp.

However, when I use readOGR to read a shapefile from mt.gov, the result is an Error in ogrInfo.

```
download.file("http://ftp.geoinfo.msl.mt.gov/Data/Spatial/MSDI/Cadastral/Parcels/Sheridan/SheridanOwnerParcel_shp.zip" , destfile="SheridanOwnerParcel_shp.zip")
#Unzip them ##
unzip("SheridanOwnerParcel_shp.zip")
SheridanCountyMTParcelShapes = readOGR(dsn=getwd(), layer="SheridanOwnerParcel_shp")
```

Resulting error :

```
Error in ogrInfo (dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv, : Cannot open layer
```

Comment: Please don't put more than one question in a post. We've fixed your projection problem and I know the solution to the second (shapefile reading) problem. If you can delete it from here and create a new question with *just that problem* then I'll answer it.

Comment: You've mutilated this question now so that my answer to one of your questions is now pointless. And as it stands we dont know where your data comes from or how you've saved it.

Answer (score 2):

`leaflet` requires vector layers to be in WGS84 coordinates.

Your shapefile is not in WGS84 coordinates.

Transform to WGS84 coordinates with:

```
SCMP_trans = spTransform(SheridanCountyMTParcelShapes,CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
```

Test leaflet *outside of shiny* with:

```
leaflet(SCMP_trans) %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons()
```

Comment: The shinyapps.io problem is a problem there and you should take it up with them (which I think you have). Let's keep this question to one question for which the solution is "reproject your map to epsg:4326".

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman.  This is the solution to this problem.  However, this led to another problem, which i have posted as another question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322990/error-when-publishing-leaflet-with-shapefile-to-shinyapps-io